# how to reflect value entered in one text box to another text box using jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to display data entered in one text box reflect on another text box

like if i enter any thing on TextBox1 i should get in TextBox2 (somthing like reflection)

this is i tried..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".valueEnter").click(function () {

    $('#message').html($('#textBox').val());

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    TextBox 1 : <input type="textbox" id="textBox" class="valueEnter"></input>

    TextBox 2 : <input type="textbox" id="message"></input>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You register a .click event for the textbox1 but you do not want it on click you want it on keydown/keyup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simple use key up function

http://jsfiddle.net/DfHSS/

```
$("#textBox").keyup(function(){
   $("#message").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: I seen your demo it's working fine but in my system it's not working pleas see this code  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#textBox").keyup(function(){
   $("#message").val($(this).val());
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
 
<div>
    TextBox 1 : <input type="textbox" id="textBox"></input>

    TextBox 2 : <input type="textbox" id="message"></input>
</div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: please attach latest version of jquery file

Comment: it seems that you are not using jquery file

Comment: see i am using this ===> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: use this code <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>   <script> $("#textBox").keyup(function(){ $("#message").val($(this).val()); }); </script> </head> <body> <div> TextBox 1 : <input type="textbox" id="textBox"></input> TextBox 2 : <input type="textbox" id="message"></input> </div> </body> </html>

Comment: really i am not getting why it's not working in my system, i tried with other jquery examples it's working fine but why this not..? and i downloaded new one from hear http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: but your example is write.

Comment: in which browser are u testing

Comment: thanks for all, something went wrong in my system your all examples are write. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#textBox").keyup(function(){
   $("#message").val($(this).val());
});

Try the above
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should use change event or the keydown

```
$(".valueEnter").keyup(function () {

    $('.valueEnter').not(this).val($(this).val());

    });
```

Using the this selector will get the value of the textbox being edited and it will pass the value to the other textbox with the same class.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWHpD/)

Comment: sorry i am not getting out put

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add something. I just updated the code. both textbox will mirror each other

Answer (score 0):

you have to add your listener inside `.ready()` method. and also try to change your code to this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textBox").change(function () {
        $("#message").val($('#textBox').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

```
$('#text1').focus(function(){

    $(this).on('keyup' , function(){

     $('#txt2').val($(this).val());
     });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try this..

$(".valueEnter").keyup(function () {

    $('#message').html($('#textBox').val());

 });
```