# javascript post from form to section

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to get user inputted information from a form to display in another section on the page.

I have section which is the left column on the page:

```
<section id="col1">
<h1>Blog Goes Here</h1>
</section>
```

Then this form:

```
<form name="blog" action="index.html">
<label for="bhead">Heading: </label>
<input type="text" id="bhead" />
<label for="bpost">Paragraph:</label>
<textarea id="bpost" rows="5" cols="25"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Post" style="width:60px;" onclick="post()" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/blogPost.js"></script>
```

There's a call to an external js file which has this:

```
function post()
{
var heading = document.blog.bhead.value;
var content = document.blog.bpost.value;

document.getElementById('col1').innerHTML = '<h1>'+$heading+'</h1>&nbsp<p>'+$content+'</p>';
}
```

Is there a way to get the text entered into the form to display in the section with the id of col1?

Answer (score 1):

There's an error with this line:

```
document.getElementById('col1').innerHTML = '<h1>'+$heading+'</h1>&nbsp<p>'+$content+'</p>';
```

It should be `heading` and `content` instead of `$heading` and `$content`.

Comment: That's working. But when the action in the form sends the page to another page, the content disappears. How could I make it permanent?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody else had a similar problem. Check out the jQuery solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874184/how-to-reflect-value-entered-in-one-text-box-to-another-text-box-using-jquery).

They use the .keyUp() function to move the value of one textbox to another.

`$("#textBox").keyup(function(){
   $("#message").val($(this).val());
});`

Comment: Please Do include your code. This should be really a comment.

Comment: @Brofessor That jsfiddle worked on the jsfiddle site but not when I tried it from the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

remove `$` signs form `$heading` and `$content`.

use this

```
document.getElementById('col1').innerHTML = '<h1>'+heading+'</h1>&nbsp<p>'+content+'</p>';
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('col1').innerHTML = '<h1>'+$heading+'</h1>&nbsp<p>'+$content+'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in your function

Here is corrected JavaScript code:

```
function post()
 {
      var heading = document.blog.bhead.value;
      var content = document.blog.bpost.value;
      document.getElementById('col1').innerHTML =  '<h1>'+heading+'</h1>&nbsp<p>'+content+'</p>'; 
 }
```

If you're using JQuery, code:

```
 function post()
 {
      var heading = document.blog.bhead.value;
      var content = document.blog.bpost.value;
     $('#col1').html('<h1>'+heading+'</h1>&nbsp<p>'+content+'</p>'); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you included the '$' sign, let me make this addition too,

As many of us have said here, the below one is correct

```
function post()
  {
   var heading = document.blog.bhead.value;
   var content = document.blog.bpost.value;

   document.getElementById('col1').innerHTML='<h1>'+heading+'</h1>&nbsp<p>'+content+'</p>';
```

}

Also, Since '$' is a valid JavaScript identifier, the below code also hold correct

```
function post()
  {
   var $heading = document.blog.bhead.value;
   var $content = document.blog.bpost.value;

   document.getElementById('col1').innerHTML='<h1>'+$heading+'</h1>&nbsp<p>'+$content+'</p>';
  }
```